# How to using sed to change the last character from a match line

Tags: sed, awk, regular-expressions

How to using sed to change the last character from a match line ?

Exemple:
/etc/network/interfaces

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 150.0.3.50
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 150.0.3.0
        gateway 150.0.3.6


auto eth.....
```

How can I change only the host octet of the gateway ? I've a lot of machines to do that and each one is in a different network, but the gateway's octet is always the same.

Comment: Can you be more specific providing both an example from and example to?  Most likely, your answer is going to be something like `sed -e 's@\(gateway [0-9.]+\)\.[0-9]+@\1.6@i'` but it's hard to know for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your gateway is `150.0.3.254`
You can do it this way:

```
sed -i -E 's/([ \t]+gateway[ \t])+[0-9.]+/\1150.0.3.254/' /etc/network/interfaces
```

Let me explain how it works:

- `-i` -> Means replace the file
- `-E` -> Use Extended regular expressions, avoids escape especial characters like `(` to `\(`
- `'s/<PATTERN>/<REPLACEMENT>/' -> the`s` means substitution for the pattern to the replacemnet
- `[ \t]+`  -> Space or Tab one or more occurrences.
- `[0-9.]+` -> Numbers from 0 to 9 and dot one or more occurrences (for the ip)
- `(PATTERN) \1` -> The pattern inside `()` is stored as group 1 `\1`, so it will be used on the replacement (in this case spaces or tabs + "gateway" + spaces or tabs)
- `150.0.3.254`  -> Is the desired gateway

Best regards

Comment: IIRC BSD sed uses different command line area and doesn't support the in place option

Comment: Hello, I assumed that the code is used on linux. I never used BSD

Comment: Sure but I'm just saying it's different.

Comment: How it should executed on BSD?